# Error in eval(expr, p): object 'X' not found; predict (BayesARIMAX)

Tags: r, time-series, bayesian, arima

I am trying to use BayesARIMAX to model and predict us gdp (you can find the data here: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/GDP).I followed the example (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BayesARIMAX/BayesARIMAX.pdf) to build my model. I didnt have any major issue to build the model(used error handling to overcome [Getting chol.default error when using BayesARIMAX in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70164422/getting-chol-default-error-when-using-bayesarimax-in-r) issue). However could not get the prediction of the model. I tried to look for solution and there is no example of predicting the model that is build using BayesARIMAX. Every time that I run the "predict" I get the following error:
"Error in eval(expr, p) : object 'X' not found"

Here is my code.

```
library(xts)
library(zoo)
library(tseries)
library(tidyverse)
library(fpp2)
gdp <- read.csv("GDP.csv", head = T)
date.q <- as.Date(gdp[, 1], "%Y-%m-%d")
gdp <- xts(gdp[,2],date.q)

train.row <- 248
number.row <- dim(merge.data)[1]
gdp.train <- gdp[1:train.row]
gdp.test <- gdp[(train.row+1):number.row]
date.test <- date.q[(train.row+1):number.row]
library(BayesARIMAX)

#wrote this function to handle randomly procuded error due to MCMC simulation
test_function <- function(a,b,P=1,Q=1,D=1,error_count = 0)
{
  tryCatch(
    {
      
      model =  BayesARIMAX(Y=a,X = b,p=P,q=Q,d=D)
      return(model)
    },
    error = function(cond)
    {
      error_count=error_count+1
      if (error_count <40)
      {
        
        test_function(a,b,P,Q,D,error_count = error_count)
      }
      else
      {
        print(paste("Model doesnt converge for ARIMA(",P,D,Q,")"))
        print(cond)
      }
    }
  )
  
}
set.seed(1)
x = rnorm(length(gdp.train),4,1)
bayes_arima_model <- test_function(a = gdp.train,b=x,P = 3,D = 2,Q = 2)
bayes_arima_pred <- xts(predict(bayes_arima_model[[1]],newxreg = x[1:3])$pred,date.test)
```

and here is the error code

> Error in eval(expr, p) : object 'X' not found

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I resolve the issue after reading through the BayesARIMAX code (https://rdrr.io/cran/BayesARIMAX/src/R/BayesianARIMAX.R) . I basically created the variable "X" and passed it to predict function to get the result. You just have to set the length of X variable equal to number of prediction.

here is the solution code for prediction.

```
X <- c(1:3)
bayes_arima_pred <- xts(predict(bayes_arima_model[[1]],newxreg = X[1:3])$pred,date.test)
```

which gave me the following results.

```
bayes_arima_pred
               [,1]
2009-01-01 14462.24
2009-04-01 14459.73
2009-07-01 14457.23
```